# Get name of object from string and use it that way

Tags: c#, loops, checkbox, checklistbox

The title may not make as much sense as im I can make here..

Say that I have 5 checklistboxes.. For each of these I want a single checkbox I can click to check/uncheck all the elements in the corresponding checklistbox..

I could easily do this by using CheckedChanged on each of the checkboxes that checks/unchecks all the elements in their lists.. But I want to make one function that does this for every list.. How can I do this ? I was thinking something along the lines of this

```
    private void internalModsChkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testfunktion("internalModsChkAll", "internalModsChkList");
    }

    private void testfunktion(string from, string to) 
    {
        if ([from].Checked == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < [to].Items.Count; i++)
            {
                [to].SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < [to].Items.Count; i++)
            {
                [to].SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope you can see what im trying to do here.. However the above doesnt work :(

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you post your markup for all of the check box lists or is this hypothetical?

Comment: What framework are you using for the front end? Is this a WPF application or Web app?

Comment: Instead of string, pass `CheckedListBox` to method

Comment: lazyberezovsky your suggestion is working !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms, I think you're looking for Controls.Find() and a Cast:

```
    private void testfunktion(string from, string to) 
    {  
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(from, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox CB = (CheckBox)matches[0];
            matches = this.Controls.Find(to, true);
            if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is CheckedListBox)
            {
                CheckedListBox CLB = (CheckedListBox)matches[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < CLB.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    CLB.SetItemChecked(i, CB.Checked);
                }    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by lazyberezovsky heres the same code as in original post, but working, for others to see :-)

```
    private void internalModsChkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkAll(internalModsChkAll, internalModsChkList);
    }

    public void checkAll(CheckBox from, CheckedListBox to) 
    {
        if (from.Checked == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < to.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                to.SetItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < to.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                to.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
```